# Sidekiq / active job not sending e-mails in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sidekiq, rails-activejob

When I try to send e-mails with Sidekiq (5.1.3) and Rails (5.1.6) in production using ActiveJob's deliver_later, e-mails are not being sent (deliver_now works fine). The job gets processed and Sidekiq reports it as such. The logs show a successful start & done:

`2018-09-14T14:12:18.031Z 14029 TID-mncgx ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-665575b056e61ef84a434c97 INFO: done: 0.84 sec`

The only thing missing is the delivery of the actual e-mail. I've enabled 'raise_delivery_errors', but nothing is being raised. I'm sending my email through Mailgun.

I'm inclined to think something's going wrong with Sidekiq, because I had ActiveJob configured before (with the default adapter, :async) and deliver_later worked properly. Only after adding Sidekiq it stopped working. I've tried it with many different e-mails and in the end I created an extremely simple mailer, just for debugging this issue.

Here's the code of my 'job':

`SimpleMailer.test.deliver_later`

And here's the code of my mailer:

```
class SimpleMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.simple_mailer.test.subject
  #
  def test
    @greeting = "Hi"
    mail to: xx, from: xx, subject: 'Well hello"
  end
```

Thanks a lot in advance! I've been searching for quite some time now and have lost almost all inspiration - any help (on where to look) would be amazing. I could also provide more info, but I don't really know what's more to provide.

Comment: Can we see the code for your Sidekiq job please.

Comment: Naturally (added it), though it's not very spectacular :p

`SimpleMailer.test.deliver_later`

Comment: Have you tried it with deliver_now?

Comment: What are you using to perform the deliveries? What SMTP server? Did you check those logs?

Comment: BenToogood, yes (as I mentioned in my post), and it works.

gasc I'm using Mailgun to deliver the e-mails, they don't end up in their logs. Or do you mean another log?